# trigger.io - Embed external website

Tags: trigger.io

I would like to embed an external website in my app, so I tried it with the  tag here:

```
<iframe src="http://www.uniteich.at" frameborder="0" width="420" height="315"></iframe>
```

But I get the following error: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL content://io.trigger.forge2dd999d0f14b11e1bc8612313d1adcbe/src/index.html from frame with URL http://www.uniteich.at/. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

So is there a good solution to embed a website in ios/android app with trigger.io?

Thanks in advance,

enne

EDIT: Ok, to make it more clear what I want: I would just like to load an external website as soon as a user clicks on a specific tabbar button at the bottom. I made this event-handler:

```
  var dessertButton = forge.tabbar.addButton({
text: "Uniteich",
icon: "img/strawberry.png",
index: 2
}, function (button) {
button.onPressed.addListener(function () {
    //LOAD EXTERNAL WEBSITE IN CONTENT CONTAINER HERE
});
});
```

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is cross domain requests.  For more information read the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

To get around this you will need to utilize [forge.request](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html#modules-request).  After adding www.uniteich.at to your config permissions first try the simple forge.get like this:

```
button.onPressed.addListener(function () {
   var mainElement = document.getElementById("main");

   forge.request.get("http://www.uniteich.at/index.html", function(content) {
     mainElement.innerHTML = content;
   }, 
   function(error) {
     mainElement.innerHTML = "<b>Error</b>" + error.message;
   });
});
```

And if that does not work or not enough (I am not at my dev computer right now) you can utilize more options with forge.request.ajax.